# Git (git) not found when running buildozer in ubuntu

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

when trying to compile my kivy app with buildozer into apk in virtual ubuntu machine the following error appears:

```
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
# Git (git) not found, please install it.
```

What does it mean and what should I do to fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you should install git. In Debian, this should work:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```